# increased VDI size for VM but Ubuntu still says I am low on space

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, vdi

I had a 8 GB VDI which i filled to capacity, so then I cloned it into a larger 25 GB vdi but when I go to setting in Ubuntu 12.04LTS it says my disk is still 7.9gb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you're seeing the size of the file-system.
Try to boot in a live distro with `gparted` and check if the disk is 25Gb. If so you can resize or rearrange partition to fill the unallocated space.